# Storing pointers wrong/not using Unordered_map.find correctly

Tags: c++11, compiler-construction

so the title essentially says it all. I am writing a symbol table in c++ for a compiler project I am working on, and all is going well except for looking up identifiers in the table.

So this is how I store into the table (pseudo like):

```
vector<symbolTable*>* symbolStack = new symbolTable();
//where a symbolStack is a vector of unordered_maps (symbolTables), 
//each iteration in vector referencing a new block of code. 


string* check = new string(root->children[0]->lexicode->c_str());
symbol* sym = new symbol();
...... //setting sym info
symbol_entry pair = make_pair(check, test) 
//the unordered_map has keys of (string*, symbol*)
symbolStack[tableNumber]->insert(pair);
```

I am pretty solid that this works, as I have tested printing the size/infos from the map and it all seems to be storing as expect. Here is where the problem is happening for me (this takes place in a different function later):

```
for(int i = 0; i =< tableNumber;i++){
auto finder = symbolStack[i]->find(checkS) //checkS == check from above 
if(finder == symbolStack[i]->end()) cout<<not found;
else cout<<we did it!!!!
```

My else is never reached. However, if I do this assuming the string*->c_str() == "test":

```
cout<<string->c_str(); // prints out "test"
cout<<finder->second->c_str() //prints out "test".
```

So the question. Why is it finding the key, and knowing it found the key, but at the same time returning that is has reached the end of the symbol stack without finding it? I have been trying to figure this out for a good 4 days solid now. Is it that my pointers are somehow off? Any insight is appreciated greatly.

Answer (score 0):

So somewhat answer to my own question.

First I will say this: I have concluded the comparison with find() or similar methods do not work because for some reason the pointers are not matching up. I have no clue why this is still, or what I am doing wrong.

What I did to solve my issue and complete my code is this:

```
for(int k = 0; k<= tableNumber; k++){
    unordered_map<string*,symbol*>::iterator it;
    for(it = symbolStack[k]->begin(); it != symbolStack[k]->end(); it++)
      {  
         string a = targetString->c_str();
         string b = it->first->c_str();
         if(a.compare(b) == 0) cout<<"You have found the match! \n";
       }

      }
   }
```

So this answers how to get it working pragmatically if somebody else is in a similar ship, however not really answers *why* my other attempt failed other than noticing the pointer values were different.

Answer (score 0):

In `symbolTable` you store pointers to strings as keys, not strings themselves. Therefore `unordered_map` compares pointers, not strings, and cannot find matching items. When you reconstruct the key string (as in your answer, using `string b = it->first->c_str()`), the comparison on strings works again. So, either you need to store `string` instead of `string *` in `symbolTable`, or you need to provide your own comparison function that will compare keys of type `string *`.